# Highlight Animation Only Works Every Other Time the Button is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When the `button` is clicked: the `div` element is highlighted green, and then the green fades away.

It works, but it only works *every other time*.

- The 1st, 3rd, 5th... time you click the button the animation occurs.
- The 2nd, 4th, 6th... time you click the button the animation *does not* occur.

**Question**: How can I make the animation occur *every time* the button is clicked?

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('div').toggleClass("success-highlight-animation");
});
```

```css
/*********************************************/
/*********************************************/
/* Fades in success color, then fades it out */
.success-highlight-animation {
  -moz-animation: highlight 2s ease 0s 1 alternate ;
  -webkit-animation: highlight 2s ease 0s 1 alternate;
  animation: highlight 2s ease 0s 1 alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes highlight {
  from { background-color: #dff0d8;}
  to {background-color: white;}
}

@-moz-keyframes highlight {
  from { background-color: #dff0d8;}
  to {background-color: white;}
}
// end .success-highlight-animation
/*********************************************/
/*********************************************/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <button>click</button>


<div>
  When the button is clicked this shows a highlight that slowly fades away.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the 2nd, 4th, etc. times are removing the css class. 1st, 3rd, etc. are adding it. You need remove the class in your function once the animation is finished.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').removeClass("success-highlight-animation");
  }, 2000);
  $('div').addClass("success-highlight-animation");
});
```

```css
/*********************************************/
/*********************************************/
/* Fades in success color, then fades it out */
.success-highlight-animation {
  -moz-animation: highlight 2s ease 0s 1 alternate ;
  -webkit-animation: highlight 2s ease 0s 1 alternate;
  animation: highlight 2s ease 0s 1 alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes highlight {
  from { background-color: #dff0d8;}
  to {background-color: white;}
}

@-moz-keyframes highlight {
  from { background-color: #dff0d8;}
  to {background-color: white;}
}
// end .success-highlight-animation
/*********************************************/
/*********************************************/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <button>click</button>


<div>
  When the button is clicked this shows a highlight that slowly fades away.
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, unfortunately you need to remove it in a separate animation frame. updated my snippet

Comment: This will stop the animation with multiple clicks and is dependent on time and not the user's behavior which could be problematic. In this case we have have some finished animation listeners we can bind to `transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd`

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are toggling the class on each click, 1st click toggles the class ON, 2nd click toggles it OFF.

You should toggle it off automatically after 2 seconds so the next time the button is clicked, it can toggle it ON again.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
   $('div').addClass("success-highlight-animation");
   window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('div').removeClass('success-highlight-animation');
   }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: This will make the div have a lot of classes

Comment: **It's important to note that this method does not replace a class. It simply adds the class, appending it to any which may already be assigned to the elements.**
Extracted from [the oficial page](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener on `webkitAnimationEnd` and remove the class after the animation ends.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('div').addClass("success-highlight-animation");
});

var div = document.querySelector('div');

function callback() {
    div.classList.remove('success-highlight-animation');
}

div.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", callback, false);
```

```css
/*********************************************/
/*********************************************/
/* Fades in success color, then fades it out */
.success-highlight-animation {
  -moz-animation: highlight 2s ease 0s 1 alternate ;
  -webkit-animation: highlight 2s ease 0s 1 alternate;
  animation: highlight 2s ease 0s 1 alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes highlight {
  from { background-color: #dff0d8;}
  to {background-color: white;}
}

@-moz-keyframes highlight {
  from { background-color: #dff0d8;}
  to {background-color: white;}
}
// end .success-highlight-animation
/*********************************************/
/*********************************************/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <button>click</button>


<div>
  When the button is clicked this shows a highlight that slowly fades away.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the class is **still active** on the div but the animation has already run. Thus every other time you click it, you're only removing the class—you're not playing the animation again.

What you should do is add the class then remove it after the two seconds is up.

There may be a more elegant solution, but this works:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('div').toggleClass("success-highlight-animation");
  setTimeout(function() {$('div').toggleClass("success-highlight-animation");}, 2000);
});
```

```css
/*********************************************/
/*********************************************/
/* Fades in success color, then fades it out */
.success-highlight-animation {
  -moz-animation: highlight 2s ease 0s 1 alternate ;
  -webkit-animation: highlight 2s ease 0s 1 alternate;
  animation: highlight 2s ease 0s 1 alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes highlight {
  from { background-color: #dff0d8;}
  to {background-color: white;}
}

@-moz-keyframes highlight {
  from { background-color: #dff0d8;}
  to {background-color: white;}
}
// end .success-highlight-animation
/*********************************************/
/*********************************************/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <button>click</button>


<div>
  When the button is clicked this shows a highlight that slowly fades away.
</div>
```

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('div').toggleClass("success-highlight-animation");
  setTimeout(function() {$('div').toggleClass("success-highlight-animation");}, 2000);
});
```

Cheers!

Comment: If you press the button fast a few times, the div will repeat the action a few times, even when you stop clicking

Comment: It would be better to use addClass/removeClass explicitly so that the toggle that happens in the timeout is well defined.